# Lua and patterns workaround

Tags: design-patterns, lua, lua-table, lua-patterns

I have a string that contains name of files (including complete fullpath) separated by a "|", at the end is a number who indicated the current file (is for a player).
So I just wanna keep it with the name of the files, but right now I have to use match function 2 times, one for separation and the other for cut it out the path. I wonder if and how is possible to do this with only one.
Ex.
I have:

```
local s = "W:\\Videos\\Tokyo Ghoul\\[Tokyo Ghoul][EP01]Tragedia.mkv|W:\\Videos\\Tokyo Ghoul\\[Tokyo Ghoul][EP02]Incubación.mkv|W:\\Videos\\Tokyo Ghoul\\[Tokyo Ghoul][EP03]Paloma.mkv|W:\\Videos\\Tokyo Ghoul\\[Tokyo Ghoul][EP04]Cena.mkv|2";
```

So i do:

```
for val in s:gmatch('(.-)|') do
    print(val);
    table.insert(list, {
            type = "item",
            icon = icon;
            text = val:match(".*\\(.*)")});
end
```

I receive:

```
[Tokyo Ghoul][EP01]Tragedia.mkv
[Tokyo Ghoul][EP02]Incubación.mkv
[Tokyo Ghoul][EP03]Paloma.mkv
[Tokyo Ghoul][EP04]Cena.mkv
```

What I want is just use only one gmatch function. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try `s:gmatch("[^|]*\\([^\\|]*)|")`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for val in s:gmatch('.-\\(%[.-)|') do
    print(val)
end
```